# How to select a Resource by using the Name attribute and then return another attribute value

Tags: vba, ms-project

Within MS Project I want to write VBA code that locates a Resource in the Resource sheet using the Resource.Name attribute and then can return a value against that Resource.  For example I want to say find the Resource called 'John' and then be able to return his 'Initials', 'Std.Rate' etc.

```
For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks

For Each asn In T.Assignments
    If asn.ResourceName = "John" Then  'Find the User Resources

     'Insert code here that finds John in the Resource sheet and returns his 
      'Std.Rate


    End If
Next asn
Next T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment) object has a property ([Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment.resource)) that returns the associated [Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource) object which makes this a trivial task:

```
For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks

For Each asn In T.Assignments
    If asn.ResourceName = "John" Then  'Find the User Resources

     ' print resource's initials and standard rate 
     Debug.Print asn.Resource.Initials, asn.Resource.StandardRate

    End If
Next asn
Next T
```